# ModuleNotFoundError : No module named 'gnuradio'

Tags: python, decoding, gnuradio, docker-toolbox, lora

I am trying to install gr-lora using https://github.com/rpp0/gr-lora on my ubuntu 20.02. I have already installed docker toolbox successfully from the installation section. But then trying testing section it has command  $ ./lora_receive_file_nogui.py which basically is used to test the installation. When I run to run that .py file it showed me error "ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'gnuradio'. Then I tried to install gnuradio for ubuntu. One of the source also suggested me to use python 2.7 instead of python 3. I tried everything but it's still showing me the same error. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: you need to first install the right version of GNU Radio, then build and install the software that depends on it. This problem is not specific to GNU Radio, docker or lora.

Answer (score 1):

> When I run to run that .py file it showed me error "ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'gnuradio'.

You need to execute `./lora_receive_file_nogui.py` *inside* the container and not in your host.

I just tested it few times and it mostly work as documented - sometimes on the first run it does not decode anything but on the second run you get few messages. Here is the full output of one of my tests.

```
$ ./docker_run_grlora.sh 

[root@8c063de13ece apps]# ./lora_receive_file_nogui.py 
[?] Download test LoRa signal to decode? [y/N] y
[+] Downloading https://research.edm.uhasselt.be/probyns/lora/usrp-868.1-sf7-cr4-bw125-crc-0.sigmf-data -> ./example-trace.sigmf-data . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
[+] Downloading https://research.edm.uhasselt.be/probyns/lora/usrp-868.1-sf7-cr4-bw125-crc-0.sigmf-meta -> ./example-trace.sigmf-meta . .
[+] Configuration: 868.1 MHz, SF 7, CR 4/8, BW 125 kHz, prlen 8, crc on, implicit off
[+] Decoding. You should see a header, followed by 'deadbeef' and a CRC 5 times.
Bits (nominal) per symbol:  3.5
Bins per symbol:    128
Samples per symbol:     1024
Decimation:         8
/root/.gnuradio/prefs/vmcircbuf_default_factory: No such file or directory
vmcircbuf_createfilemapping: createfilemapping is not available
[+] Done
[root@8c063de13ece apps]# ./lora_receive_file_nogui.py 
[+] Skipping download.
[+] Configuration: 868.1 MHz, SF 7, CR 4/8, BW 125 kHz, prlen 8, crc on, implicit off
[+] Decoding. You should see a header, followed by 'deadbeef' and a CRC 5 times.
Bits (nominal) per symbol:  3.5
Bins per symbol:    128
Samples per symbol:     1024
Decimation:         8
 04 90 40 de ad be ef 70 0d
 04 90 40 de ad be ef 70 0d
 04 90 40 de ad be ef 70 0d
 04 90 40 de ad be ef 70 0d
 04 90 40 de ad be ef 70 0d
[+] Done
[root@8c063de13ece apps]# exit
exit

$ docker images rpp0/gr-lora
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
rpp0/gr-lora        latest              118b17c9b50d        2 years ago         2.56GB
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me out. It was executed suceessfully